# Sobreponer registros de entrada y salida

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

Necesito que se sobrepongan registros en una misma consulta de una tabla.

Los registros de la tabla son los siguientes:

```
|---|--------|----------------|------------|-----------------|----------------|-----------------|----------------|
|Id | Nombre |     E-mail     |    Fecha   | Hora de Entrada | Hora de Comida | Hora de Regreso | Hora de Salida |
|---|--------|----------------|------------|-----------------|----------------|-----------------|----------------|
|28 | Carlos | Carlos90@gmail | 2008-07-17 | 00:37:42        | 00:00:00       | 00:00:00        | 00:00:00       |
|29 | Carlos | Carlos90@gmail | 2008-07-17 | 00:00:00        | 00:00:00       | 00:00:00        | 00:37:49       |
|---|--------|----------------|------------|-----------------|----------------|-----------------|----------------|
```

A continuación comparto el código con el que se ingresa la hora de entrada:

```
include "../Funciones/Conexion.php";
$mysqli = inicio();

$nombre = $_POST["nombre"];
$email = $_POST["email"];
$fecha = date('d/m/y');  
$hora = date('H:i:s');


$sql = "INSERT INTO chequeo (nombre,email,fecha,hora)
        VALUES ('$nombre','$email','$fecha','$hora');";

$query = mysqli_query($mysqli,$sql);
if ($query){
  echo "<script>alert(\"Exito al registrar.\"); </script>";
  echo "<script>location.href='../Usuario.php'</script>";
} else {
  echo "<script>alert(\"Error al registrar\"); </script>";
  echo "<script>location.href='../Usuario.php'</script>";
```

Tengo ademas este otro donde se ingresa el de salida:

```
include "../Funciones/Conexion.php";
$mysqli = inicio();

$nombre = $_POST["nombre"];
$email = $_POST["email"];
$fecha = date('d/m/y');  
$horaS = date('H:i:s');


$sql = "INSERT INTO chequeo (nombre,email,fecha,horaS)
        VALUES ('$nombre','$email','$fecha','$horaS');";

$query = mysqli_query($mysqli,$sql);
if ($query){
  echo "<script>alert(\"Exito al registrar.\"); </script>";
  echo "<script>location.href='../Usuario.php'</script>";
} else {
  echo "<script>alert(\"Error al registrar\"); </script>";
  echo "<script>location.href='../Usuario.php'</script>";
}
```

Lo que requiero es que mi consulta quede asi:

```
|----|--------|----------------|------------|----------------|---------------|---------------------------|----------------|
| Id | Nombre | E-mail         | Fecha      | Hora de Entrada| Hora de Comida| Hora de Regreso de Comida | Hora de Salida |
|----|--------|----------------|------------|----------------|---------------|---------------------------|----------------|
| 28 | Carlos | Carlos90@gmail | 2008-07-17 | 00:37:42       | 00:00:00      | 00:00:00                  | 00:40:20       |
|----|--------|----------------|------------|----------------|---------------|---------------------------|----------------|
```

```html
<?php
 

 $consulta= "SELECT * FROM chequeo WHERE nombre='".$_SESSION["nombre"]."'";
 
      if ($resultado = $mysqli->query($consulta)) 
      {
        while ($fila = $resultado->fetch_row()) 
        {    
      

    
          echo "<tr>";
          echo "<td>$fila[0]</td><td>$fila[1]</td><td>$fila[2]</td><td>$fila[3]</td><td>$fila[4]</td><td>$fila[5]</td><td style='text-align: center;'>$fila[6]</td><td>$fila[7]</td><td>$fila[8]</td><td>$fila[9]</td>";  
          echo"<td>";           
    

          echo "</td>";
          echo "</tr>";
        }
        $resultado->close();
      }
      $mysqli->close();      

?>
```

Comment: Podias agregar la descripción de la tabla que estas usando?

Comment: Claro Juan Ya Esta Espero Y Me Puedas Ayudar

Comment: te recomendaría lo siguiente: verificar si existe el registro del usuario, entonces no existe registro para la fecha haces un insert de hora de entrada, de lo contrario dependiendo de tu parametro(rango de horas en que se puede registrar una entrada) solo actualiza el siguiente campo(no insertes datos nuevo), y asi te vas hasta que completes los registros del dia, ten en consideracion que hay usuarios que se le olvida marcar es por eso el parametro de rango de hora posibles para marcar entrada, comidad, salidas.

Comment: No la veo. Pero no importa, tampoco habia entendido la pregunta. Lo que dice @FranciscoNúñez es correcto. Para la actualización la instrucción es UPDATE en lugar de INSERT.

Comment: @Juan la descripcion que el hace es de como espera que se guarde los registros... digamos que el ya tiene una tabla pero no quiere un registro por cada evento de la jornada, el quiere que solo se genere 1 registro al día y este se actualice dependiendo de los eventos de cada jornada, es por eso que yo le propuse el parámetro de rango de horas y de la revisión de si existe el registro.

Comment: @FranciscoNúñez Sí, lo entendí después de ver tu comentario.

Comment: Creo que seria conveniente que antes de hacer cualquier cosa hagas ciertas validaciones, como por ejemplo: Antes de cargar (`eg: INSERT`) la `hora de entrada`, deberías validar que `NO` exista un registro para ese `email` en esa `fecha`. Antes de actualizar (`UPDATE`) la `hora de salida` debería validar de que `SI`  exista un registro para ese `email` en esa `fecha` y que ademas la `hora de salida` igual a `00:00:00`. De lo contrario tu código actual se presta a que se carguen datos inconsistentes.

Comment: La primer tabla le falta normalizar para que no haya redundancia de datos!

Answer (score 0):

Usando GROUP BY, MIN y MAX en la query podria hacerse:

```
SELECT MIN(Id), Nombre, E-mail, Fecha , MAX(Hora de Entrada).MAX(Hora de Comida), MAX(Hora de Regreso), MAX(Hora de Salida) FROM chequeo WHERE Nombre = :nombre GROUP BY Nombre, E-mail, Fecha;
```